# Customize order by query

Tags: mysql

I want to customize order by query. I want to order records according to subscription type that is Gold member first, then Silver and then Bronze members.

Currently my query is

```
select * from user ORDER BY subsciption_type ASC
```

Returning me in order of Bronze, Gold and Silver (which obviously in alphabetical order and is not as per my expectation).

What changes should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify custom order, you need the `ORDER BY FIELD` function

```
select * from user ORDER BY FIELD(subsciption_type, 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze')
```